# NoMethodError when attempting to display user information on a Profile Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, profile, nomethoderror

I'm trying to make a simple profile page using a registration/login system with devise.  I can register, login, and redirect to a profile page no problem, however, when I attempt to insert variables that relate to a user to their profile page, I keep running into a NoMethodError.  I DO NOT want to use current_user to display the information because each profile page has to display that specific users information.  I've searched everywhere for a solution to this and I have no idea why this won't work.  Here's all the code:

index.html.erb

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
<div id="user_nav">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
    <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> or <%= link_to "sign in", new_user_session_path %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= @user.firstname %>
You are signed in
```

Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :firstname, :lastname
end
```

route.rb

```
Test1::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :user
  authenticated :user do
  root :to => 'users#show'
  end
  root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

Error Message

```
NoMethodError in Users#show

Showing /Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/test1/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `firstname' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= @user.firstname %>
2: You are signed in
Rails.root: /Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/test1

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/users/show.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___52288684_2184635920'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it should be:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: BTW, I guess that given the route prefix, the user should be directly accessed through `current_user`

Comment: If I use that option I receive the following error:  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

Couldn't find User without an ID
Rails.root: /Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/test1

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:3:in `show'

Comment: What are the params when you hit that action?

Comment: I tried passing the username and I still get my initial error.